# Trying to install composer to get set up with Laravel framework

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am trying to install composer on my Mac so that I can use the Laravel framework.  I successfully downloaded composer through the terminal, and then I moved composer.phar to to usr/local/bin using the command:  `sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin`.

I then changed directories to my root directory where I have the laravel-master files.  After changing to this directory in the terminal, and then using the command: `composer install`

I receive the error:  `-bash: composer: command not found`

I have tried other variations (such as `php composer.phar install`, etc..), however, I keep receiving the same error.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Make sure that `/usr/local/bin` is in your `$PATH`

```
$ echo $PATH
```

Then execute

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
                                       ^^^^^^^^ you didn't rename it
```

For reference see

- [Installing composer.phar globally on *nix](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally)

Comment: when i try the last line, it reads: mv: rename composer.phar to usr/local/bin/composer: Not a directory;  Is that correct?

Comment: It seems like you're missing a forward slash in front of `usr`. It should be `/usr/local/bin/composer`

Comment: what about `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer` ?

Comment: @user1072337 Yes, thats correct! But a sudo is not necessary, at least in my case…

Comment: for me it was because I change dir right after I curl composer so of cuz it can't find composer file to move to bin

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65536 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
curl: (23) Failed writing body (233 != 16384)

Answer (score 41):

I'm running Mavericks and had same problem. I changed `/usr/local/bin/composer` to `/usr/bin/composer` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 18):

for mac os x **Mavericks** and **Yosemite** **El capitan**

Change

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

To

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer
```

Now if you just write `composer` in terminal, it will show you all available commands

Then "if running MAMP" navagate you htdocs folder and run

`composer create-project laravel/laravel laratest`

Hope that helps

Comment: This worked for me. But i don't get it. I have the other PATH too. I have a $PATH like this: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin

Comment: i am getting this error when trying this method on El Capitan - mv: rename composer.phar to /usr/bin/composer: Operation not permitted .. I Tried it with sudo !

Answer (score 14):

A quick copy-paste version including sudo:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

Comment: Thank you for your update For me, without the arguments to the php command line, the command fails with the message "php command not found" .

Comment: For others,try /usr/bin

Answer (score 0):

Now in 2017 I am using MacOS SIERRA 10.12.6 and `sudo mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer` doesn't work. It works for me `sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`. Now I can run composer instead of php composer.pha