# Can't install composer on OS X

Tags: php, macos, composer-php

I did this on terminal:

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

the output was:

```
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...

Composer successfully installed to: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar
```

then I entered:

```
$ sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin
```

No issues with this (it should work because usr/local/bin is in my $PATH). But how do I run it now? When I enter composer or composer.phar on the command line, I get:

```
-bash: composer: command not found
-bash: composer.phar: command not found
```

Comment: Can you use it as `php composer.phar`? Are permissions set correctly?

Comment: I was just looking here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079822/trying-to-install-composer-to-get-set-up-with-laravel-framework?rq=1) and everything seems to work when I do sudo mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer

Comment: Actually if you do it like this after downloading `$ mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer` Then you can use it globally by just typing `composer` in terminal.

Answer (score 7):

`.phar` is short for **PH**P **Ar**chive - it's a format that the `php` executable can read, not an executable on it's own right. To run it you should use:

```
$ php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar
```

To make your life a tad easier you could, of course, define an alias:

```
$ alias composer="php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar"
```

And then just call `composer` from your shell.

Answer (score 1):

Did u check what do u have now in your path
 `ls -al /usr/local/bin` 
Check the right to execute.

To be sure u can do:
`sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/composer.phar`

First look like should be composer.phar as you did not precise a new name in ur mv command like:
`sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`

Answer (score 0):

Did you made composer.phar executable ?
if not, just do *sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/composer.phar*

Answer (score 0):

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer |  php
$ sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
mv: rename composer.phar to /usr/local/bin/composer.phar: No such file or directory
```

Solution:
make sure composer.phar and directory local ,bin composer exist (/usr/local/bin/composer) in `$PATH`
     else

```
$ cd usr
usr$m kdir local
usr/local$m kdir bin
usr/local/bin$ mkdir composer
```

now we're sur local/bin/composer exist than

```
$sudo mv /path to composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer 
Password:
toto:~ macbookpro$ your composer.phar now is move to directory usr/local/bin/composer
```