# Ubuntu 12.04 - installing laravel

Tags: json, laravel, ubuntu-12.04

In the process of installing laravel on Ubuntu 12.04. After following the installation commands to the end, typing localhost as URL, the the server does not display anything.

I got the error:

> "[Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]
>       "https://packagist.org/packages.json" does not contain valid JSON
>       Parse error on line 1:

after typing the command `composer install`

Comment: do you move somethign in composer.json?, check if the is something wrong whit the sintax, and rememeber to use double semicolon " instead of ' in strings

Comment: Validate the contents of you `composer.json` file with [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to see what's wrong with it.

Answer (score -1):

Once you have the PHAR archive, you can either keep it in your local project directory or move to usr/local/bin to use it globally on your system. 
You can do it by

```
 $ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
 $ sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

More details are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079822/trying-to-install-composer-to-get-set-up-with-laravel-framework)